# Landing Page not tracking in 'Cross Domain' Google Analytics tracking

Tags: iframe, google-analytics

We have a product sold on our primary website, where users click a "BUY NOW" button to go to another domain, where a shopping cart is served in an iframe. Tracking is following properly, except all landing pages in Analytics are reporting as if the user landed on the iframe source page.

primarydomain.com/index.html tracking code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function trackOutboundLink(link, category, action) {
    try {
        _gaq.push(['_trackEvent', category , action]);
    } catch(err){}

 setTimeout(function() {
        document.location.href = link.href;
    }, 100);
}

var _gaq = _gaq || [];
var pluginUrl = '//www.google-analytics.com/plugins/ga/inpage_linkid.js';
_gaq.push(['_require', 'inpage_linkid', pluginUrl]);
_gaq.push(['_setAccount', 'UA-ourtrackingcodehere']);
_gaq.push(['_setDomainName', 'none']);
_gaq.push(["_setAllowLinker", true]);
_gaq.push(['_trackPageview']);

(function() {
    var ga = document.createElement('script'); ga.type = 'text/javascript';
ga.async = true;
ga.src = ('https:' == document.location.protocol ? 'https://' : 'http://') + 'stats.g.doubleclick.net/dc.js';
    var s = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
s.parentNode.insertBefore(ga, s);
})();
</script>
```

Link to Buy:

```
<a href="https://inc.shoppingcartdomain.com/page/" onclick="_gaq.push(['_link', this.href]); return false;">
```

shoppingcartdomain.com/purchase.html tracking code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var _gaq = _gaq || [];
_gaq.push(['_require', 'inpage_linkid', pluginUrl]);
_gaq.push(['_setAccount', 'ourtrackingcode']); _gaq.push(['_setDomainName', 'none']); _gaq.push(['_setAllowLinker', true]); _gaq.push(['_trackPageview']);
(function() {
var ga = document.createElement('script'); ga.type = 'text/javascript';
ga.async = true;
ga.src = ('https:' == document.location.protocol ? 'https://ssl' :
'http://www') + '.google-analytics.com/ga.js';
var s = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
s.parentNode.insertBefore(ga, s); })();
_gaq.push(function() {
var pageTracker = _gat._getTrackerByName();
var iframe = document.getElementById('apiframe');
iframe.src = pageTracker._getLinkerUrl(iframe.src);
});
</script>
```

iframe code on the page:

```
<iframe id="apiframe" src="https://inc.shoppingcartdomain.com/page/eDirect" width="100%" height="800" allowtransparency="true" frameborder="0" scrollbars=0><p>Your browser does not support iframes.</p></iframe>
```

shoppingcartdomain.com iframe source tracking code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
            var _gaq = _gaq || []; 
                _gaq.push(['_setAccount', 'vendortrackingcode']);
                _gaq.push(['_setDomainName', 'none']);
                _gaq.push(['_setAllowLinker', true]);
                _gaq.push(['_setSessionCookieTimeout', 3600000]);
                _gaq.push(['_trackPageview']);   _gaq.push(['sec._setAccount', 'ourtrackingcode']);
            _gaq.push(['sec._setDomainName', 'none']);
            _gaq.push(['sec._setAllowLinker', true]);
            _gaq.push(['sec._trackPageview']);
            (function() {
                var ga = document.createElement('script'); ga.type = 'text/javascript'; ga.async = true;
                ga.src = ('https:' == document.location.protocol ? 'https://ssl' : 'http://www') + '.google-analytics.com/ga.js';
                var s = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0]; s.parentNode.insertBefore(ga, s);
            })();
        </script>
```

To be clear, everything is tracking properly (transaction id, amount, product, source, campaign, etc) EXCEPT the landing page. They're all showing up as landing on the shopping cart's iframe page.

Comment: I'd guess the issue is with the 'iframe.src = pageTracker._getLinkerUrl(iframe.src);' line. Specifically, you could replace the iframe.src with a specific URL to double-check this.

Comment: This didn't seem to fix the problem.